# Problems with nsdate conversion

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsdate

I'm trying to convert a nsstring to nsdate and I am getting a weird behavior.

I try to convert these dates:

2012-11-14 13:35:05

2012-11-14 13:33:53

2012-10-22 12:56:27

2012-10-22 12:56:23

and more...

with this code:

```
NSString *createdString = [conversationFromServer objectForKey:@"created"];
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"];
NSTimeZone *gmt = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
[formatter setTimeZone:gmt];
NSDate *created = [formatter dateFromString:createdString];
```

As you can see, the dates have the same pattern, but I can't convert the first and the second date. If I log the results, all of them in string are correct, but in nsdate the first and the second ones is nil.

Any solution? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use HH in uppercase:

```
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
```

Comment: That is! I dont know why it worked with all of them except with that 2 dates...Thank you!.

Comment: The lowercase h is used for Hour in am/pm (1-12). Since the last two dates are within that range they work. The first two have 13 and are out of that range.